# C# MVC 4 - Dynamically calling models from a single controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model

I have an Admin controller that needs to delete UIDs from about multiple different models. Can I select the model by passing a string? Here is an **example** controller action of what I would like to do (of course this doesn't work):

```
private ModelEntities db = new ModelEntities();

public ActionResult ConfirmDelete(String ModelNameString, Int32 id)
{
    ModelNameString data = db.ModelNameString.Find(id);
    return View(data);
}
```

Are there any other ways to combine standard tasks for all models into a single controller action? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to implement on interface (e.g. IDynamicTable) and performing data operations with a mapping file?

Comment: I've only been using C# for 4 days (moving over from PHP), so that's all new to me. I'm checking it out now. My database was already in place and the main goal of this is to limit code so that I don't have 15 delete actions for my 15 models.

Comment: You try to over-complicate the process and don't follow the ASP.Net MVC methodology. Perhaps start with something simpler like almost everyone do and once you are familiar with the platform you can improve your code. Usually you create a controller for your class and in this controller the delete method will be associated to the current controller (class) so in your requirements what's the point of deleting different types of object from the same controller?

Comment: This is my simple start. I'm up to deleting. My issue is that I have 15 models, and I don't want 15 separate Admin actions in 15 different controllers. That's why I run delete actions through a single AdminController. All I need is a way to dynamically select a model to delete a UID.

Comment: I think you want to develop with MVC framework but don't want to follow conventions of the new platform. .Net is not PHP, .Net MVC is not Zend, you should follow best practices and think to other developers. I think in your case .Net WebForms may be well-suited to your approach if this is a requirement.

Comment: I'm afraid you're gonna have to. The only thing I can think of, is something like "dynamic list = typeof(ModelEntities ).GetProperty(ModelNameString).GetValue(db, null);", which leaves you with a dynamic instead of an IEnumerable (so you can't query that for the item with the correct id).

Comment: Stephen, that looks like exactly what I needed... Too bad it doesn't work. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @glautrou You're approach was right. I now have a generic repository/interface which holds a universal delete command. Thanks!

Comment: I made a proper answer, I think your questions are now answered, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, implement an interface (e.g. IDynamicTable) and perform your data operations (e.g. Delete) with a mapping file?

Example: When you call YourObject.Delete(), you can check the `Type` of your `YourObject`. You can do something like this in your `Action`:

```
public ActionResult ConfirmDelete(IDynamicTable obj)
{
   // ...
   if (obj is Company)
   {
      // Delete in company table
      return View("Company");
   }
   if (obj is User)
   {
      // Delete in user table
      return View("User");
   }
   // ... 
}
```

Do not forget that ASP.Net MVC is not PHP+Zend.

Comment: Just to follow up, I am also using a generic repository which is another great way to centralize CRUD commands. http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle

Comment: Look at the "Important note" in your link, there is an updated version and some comments about the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about leaving other entities behind after deleting the main reference, you should consider doing a cascading delete. This means that when you delete the main object with the primary key, it will delete all other objects that reference this primary key.

If you have a one to many required relationship, you could do this to have your objects perform a cascading delete. You could either add a `[Required]` attribute on your required relationships in your models so that the Entity Framework will know the relationship is required or use the Fluent API.

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasRequired(p => p.Category).WithMany();
}
```

If your relationship is optional but you want cascading delete, you could do this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasOptional(p => p.Category).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

Comment: I just need the controller logic to dynamically select a model using a String variable. None of the models have a relationship.